# Azure Devops: Building a multi-project solution in release mode, but looks in debug for missing assembly

Tags: azure-devops, continuous-integration

I'm trying to build a multi-project solution in Azure DevOps for deployment to Azure. This solution builds fine on my local machine, but I get the following build error in Azure.

```
##[error]TCGTools.net\Controllers\SettingsController.cs(8,7): Error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'TCGSniperCore' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

TCGSniperCore is a .netcore library in my solution. The MVC project references this library.

After skimming the full log file, I found that the solution is building the .netcore library in release mode, but then looks for the .dll in the debug folder.

Console output when building the library:

```
CopyFilesToOutputDirectory: 
Copying file from "obj\Release\netcoreapp2.2\TCGSniperCore.dll" to 
"bin\Release\netcoreapp2.2\TCGSniperCore.dll".
TCGSniperCore -> 
D:\a\1\s\tcgsnipercore\bin\Release\netcoreapp2.2\TCGSniperCore.dll
Copying file from "obj\Release\netcoreapp2.2\TCGSniperCore.pdb" to 
"bin\Release\netco
```

Console output when building the MVC project:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(2110,5): warning MSB3245: Could not resolve this reference. Could not locate the assembly "TCGSniperCore". Check to make sure the assembly exists on disk. If this reference is required by your code, you may get compilation errors. [D:\a\1\s\TCGTools.net\TCGTools.net.csproj]
      For SearchPath "{HintPathFromItem}".
      Considered "..\tcgsnipercore\bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.2\TCGSniperCore.dll", but it didn't exist.
      For SearchPath "{RawFileName}".
      Considered treating "TCGSniperCore" as a file name, but it didn't exist.
```

I have tried the following:

1. Ensuring both projects target .netcore2.2
2. Setting the Agent pool to Hosted VS2017 in Azure DevOps
3. Setting the BuildConfiguration variable to release
4. Reproducing on my local machine. I cannot. The solution builds fine.

Why is it looking for the assembly in /debug and not /release?

Comment: SOLUTION: I edited the .csproj file with a text editor and added another hint path to the item group. 

  <ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="TCGSniperCore">
      <HintPath>..\tcgsnipercore\bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.2\TCGSniperCore.dll</HintPath>
      <HintPath>..\tcgsnipercore\bin\Release\netcoreapp2.2\TCGSniperCore.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
  </ItemGroup>

Comment: you should use the 'configuration'-property in paths instead of hardcoding 'debug'/'release'-paths

Comment: @D.J. Could you provide an example? I'm not entirely sure what / where you're talking about here.

Comment: i meant that you can use properties like 'configuration' when using paths in your project. instead of having both debug/release hintpaths i'd  have this in my csproj: "<ItemGroup> <Reference Include="TCGSniperCore"> <HintPath>..\tcgsnipercore\bin\$(configuration)\netcoreapp2.2\TCGSniperCore.dll</HintPath> </Reference> </ItemGroup>"

Comment: Perfect! I wasn't aware you could use these variables outside of Azure Devops. This helps a ton. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that it looks for the .dll based on the file path specified in the .csproj file. Edit the file (I used VS Code) and add/modify the hint path with $(configuration).

Before:

```
<ItemGroup> 
  <Reference Include="TCGSniperCore"> 
   <HintPath>..\tcgsnipercore\bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.2\TCGSniperCore.dll</HintPath> 
  </Reference>
</ItemGroup>
```

After:

```
<ItemGroup> 
  <Reference Include="TCGSniperCore"> 
   <HintPath>..\tcgsnipercore\bin\$(configuration)\netcoreapp2.2\TCGSniperCore.dll</HintPath> 
  </Reference>
</ItemGroup>
```

Thanks @D.J.